# C++17 <filesystem> returns access denied regardless of capabilites

Tags: windows-runtime, visual-studio-2019, c++-winrt

I am not sure if this is intended but creating a 'Blank App (c++/WinRT)' in VS 2019 and trying something as simple as the below will always gives access denied. Is it that only app dir and local are supported for std:: ? Or am I missing something?

```
std::filesystem::path file = LR"(C:\Users\name\Pictures\1.png)";
    auto t = std::filesystem::is_regular_file(file);
```

I have tried broadFileSystemAcess with no luck and various capabilities. I think ultimately the answer is this is something that cannot be done without using RT file access APIs instead of c++ std::

Answer (score 2):

UWP applications don't have direct access to any of the file system except:

- Read-only non-exclusive access to the package install folder
- Read/write access to an application data folder (roaming or local)
- Read/write to a private temp folder.

All other access is mediated through Windows Runtime 'brokers'.

One solution is to use Windows Runtime APIs to copy the entire file to a temporary folder and then use `std::filesystem` on the temporary copy.

Here's an example using the pictures folder:

```
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.Pickers.h"

using namespace winrt::Windows::Storage;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Storage::Pickers;

FileOpenPicker openPicker;
openPicker.ViewMode(PickerViewMode::Thumbnail);
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation(PickerLocationId::PicturesLibrary);
openPicker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".jpg");
openPicker.FileTypeFilter().Append(L".png");

auto file = co_await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
if (file)
{
    auto tempFolder = ApplicationData::Current().TemporaryFolder();
    auto tempFile = co_await file.CopyAsync(tempFolder, file.Name(), NameCollisionOption::GenerateUniqueName);
    if (tempFile)
    {
        std::filesystem::path file = LR"(tempFile.Path().c_str())";
...
        DeleteFile(tempFile.Path().c_str());
    }
}
```

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

Comment: But the OP is using the [broadFileSystemAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) capability. Isn't that supposed to grant them full access to the entire filesystem (barring file permissions requiring administrative privileges)?

Comment: "This capability works for APIs in the Windows.Storage namespace." It's still using a broker.

Comment: BTW there's no such thing as "admin" rights for a UWP. There are some restricted caps like the "broadFileSystemAccess" one, but the UWP process is still running in the AppContainer context.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up. It would appear if I want to use be able to access the filesystem with C++/WinRT then I need to use the broker as you suggested. I think my confusion came from the fact that using <filesystem> with the various C++/WinRT projects in VS2019 yielded very different results using <filesystem>:

Blank App - Access denied!
Windows Console Application (C++/WinRT) - success! 
Windows Desktop Application (C++/WinRT) - success!

Comment: The Blank app you created is for UWP. As said above, UWP has limits to access files. But the console application and desktop application are both for desktop, the desktop app has no such limits, so it will succeed.